# SAP Web Ide throwing errors when starting on mac

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

SAP Web IDE throwing errors on startup

Hello, I'm trying to setup SAP Web IDE on mac and I keep getting errors in my local like:

```
!ENTRY com.sap.webide.orionplugin 4 0 2023-03-07 08:49:11.762

!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR

!STACK 0

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.sap.webide.orionplugin [13]

  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sap.webide.orionplugin.reverseproxy

    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.sap.webide.orionplugin.reverseproxy; bundle-version="1.53.9"; singleton:="true"

       com.sap.webide.orionplugin.reverseproxy [14]

         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.sap.webide.orionplugin.reverseproxy 4 0 2023-03-07 08:49:11.776

!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR

!STACK 0

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.sap.webide.orionplugin.reverseproxy [14]

  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

I have installed java 7 version and my JAVA_HOME points to java7 as well. How to get rid of these errors?

I am updated Java home to point to java7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have multiple versions of java and orion might be picking the latest one. You can update the orion.ini config file which will be at `/Applications/SAPWebIDE/eclipse/orion.app/Contents/MacOS/orion.ini`. Add the following just before `-vmargs` attribute:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<java7version>.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Make sure jdk directory is points to java7 and both of these are in different lines.